# how to create custom layout with white boxes

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know how to create layout on the following image. I mean "white boxes with 3-dot menus".

Preview:
[image: preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few OS libraries that help you implmenting the classic Google/Android Card UI.

- [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)
- [Cards-UI](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI)

those are the most common, you can either use them or import into your code the resources that you need